# Python tkinter auto update variables from entry fields

Tags: python-3.x, math, tkinter, label, auto-update

I am creating a GUI that receives inputs from the user, performs some calculations and shows the result. Most of the similar worksheets that I have reviewed are based on placing a submit button and calculation is performed upon pressing the button. Would it be possible to generate code to do the live calculation without a submit button? 
Here is a simplified version of my code and I appreciate your feedback in advance.
All the best,
Payman

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

def main():
    master = Tk()
    master.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
    master.title("Test Form")
    master.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')

    label_sag = Label(master, text='SAG (mm):', bd=3,width=20, height= 3).grid(row=0, column=0)
    label_power = Label(master, text='POWER (D)', bd=3,width=20, height= 3).grid(row=1, column=0)


    var_sag = DoubleVar()
    range_sag = np.ndarray.tolist(np.round(np.arange(3.6, 6.1, 0.1),2))
    combo_sag = ttk.Combobox(master, values=range_sag, justify=CENTER, textvariable = var_sag)
    combo_sag.grid(row=0, column=1)
    combo_sag.current(0)
    sag = var_sag.get()

    var_power = DoubleVar()
    entry_power = Entry(master, justify=CENTER, textvariable=var_power)
    entry_power.grid(row=1, column=1)
    var_power.set(0.00)
    power = var_power.get( )

    newvartest = sag + power
    label_selection13 = Label(master, textvariable=newvartest)
    label_selection13.grid(row=2, column=1)

    master.mainloop()

    return

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with tkinter's `bind` functionality?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'll check "bind" and see how much I could get.